# Spring Security 3 and JSF 2 integration without redirecting page

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

Is it possible to integrate Spring Security 3 and JSF 2, keeping JSF working as default, instead of show the new url when the user navigates, keep the old url, without using the **redirect** JSF attribute to navigate through pages?

I can't found documentation about this. All articles I found the author redirect the page when navigate.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit like with an example?

Comment: Spring uses the url to check if page is secure. In JSF as default, when you click on a button to navigate to another page, the url doesn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the FilterSecurityInterceptor will only execute once-per-request and doesn't do security re-checking unless there is change in the url but with JSP/JSF forwards the page is rendered as a response to the current request and the url in the browser contains the address of the previous page. So for this just set once-per-request attribute to false in your http element in applicationContext thus forcing security rechecking.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" once-per-request="false">
```

and add a dispatcher for forwards in springSecurityFilterChain filter-mapping in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

More [info](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/FilterSecurityInterceptor.html#isObserveOncePerRequest%28%29)

Alternatively, you can also enable page redirection by appending the parameter faces-redirect=true to the outcome like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="page1?faces-redirect=true" value="Page1" />
</h:form>
```

But do also remember that in your case GET request looks more appropriate and as [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) says its **not** good practice to use POST for bookmarkable page-to-page navigation.

So do GET using `<h:link>` or `<h:button>`or faces-redirect=true also causes a GET request.

Also see:

- [when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [Post-Redirect-Get
  pattern](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/03/post-redirect-get-pattern.html)

Comment: Sorry for delaying to test it. It have not worked. I still need to use the faces-redirect=true to get the security working.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but I always need to do page1?faces-redirect=true even with all this configuration.

Comment: Yes Ed, I am sorry for that I will test it more extensively and open a   bug with Spring. Or if you think you have done enough research please post a bug on their site and let me know.