# Namespace or URI based spring security

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-security, authorization

I need to implement authorization based on namespace of the URI.
For example, **localhost:8080/common/***  would be accessible to all kind of users and 
**localhost:8080/admin/*** would be accessible to only admin users.

I've already used UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter for login stuff but I don't know how to check for authorization for each request.

Can anybody guide me how to implement this kind of authorization with spring security?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the

```
<intercept-url> element
```

The intercept-url element can be used to define a pattern which is matched against the URLs of incoming requests using an ant path style syntax.

For example with Spring 3.0 + using SpEL:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/common/*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/registered/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</http>
```

If you don't have SpEL support then use like this:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/common/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/registered/*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</http>
```

[Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal)

**Update** - If you are doing forwards in your JSP/JSP, you need to set the once-per-request="false" on the http element.

See also:

- [Spring Security 3 and JSF 2 integration without redirecting page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283098/spring-security-3-and-jsf-2-integration-without-redirecting-page/11287884#11287884)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I've tried the same code but this authorization happens once only at the time of login (authentication) later on it doesn't happen for each request.

Comment: So I think you are doing forwards in your JSP/JSF pages. I have updated the answer!